# Deploying dependency picklist via Deployment does not reflect in org

Tags: deployment, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm?search_text=controlling%20field) `valueSettings` and `controllingFieldValue` should be responsible for adding or removing field dependencies.

But interestingly nothing works.

I tried removing a node of `valueSettings` from a `Dependent Field` and deployed Controlling and Dependent Field both while deployment but still the dependencies are not being removed from org.

[image]

I removed the first one from the xml.

```
  <valueSettings>
        <controllingFieldValue>Circumstantial</controllingFieldValue>
        <valueName>Opting For Commerce</valueName>
  </valueSettings>
```

While deploying it does not give any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm?search_text=controlling%20field) clearly mentioned about the `valueSettings.`

valueSettings:

> Used for the settings that describe a value in a custom picklist
> field. The picklist can have its own unique value set, or inherit the
> values from a global value set. You can add field dependency values
> via Metadata API but not remove them.

Refer the [Declarative Metadata Sample Definition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm) for custom picklist

Comment: The second one seems depricated. So it means we can add dependency picklist via metadata api, but cant remove them

Comment: Also cant use the second one as its not how sfdx deploys component.  I think thats legacy deployment process.

Comment: 'Picklist (Including Dependent Picklist)'-->(This field type isn’t used in Metadata API. CustomField includes this field type for Tooling API support). Represents a picklist, a set of labels and values that can be selected from a picklist. check the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_field_types.htm#meta_type_valueset

Comment: @NagendraSingh, Refer the https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67610/manipulating-field-dependencies-with-metadata-api

Comment: That is what I said, this is not how SFDX depoys compoennt, its legacy deployment which uses that xml structure. In SFDC fields dont come as part of object.